# Ubuntu 22.04 Live USB won't start

Tags: live-usb, firmware, sgx

I'm trying to run an Ubuntu 22.04 Live USB and it won't start. Every time I try to boot from the Live USB it fails with the following error:

DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this, contact BIOS vender for fixes

x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.

The motherboard is an ASROCK Z170A-X1.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available? I am using a Gigabyte Z170 without issue. It has not gotten firmware updates for a while, but in beginning there were many updates.